# Where is the config for Samba's user-created shares?

Tags: samba

I want to tune the permissions on a share I created as a user in Nautilus. This share does not exist in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and I can't see where it would be.

Edit: Just found `~/.smb/smb.conf` but this doesn't contain any share information, just information, I suspect, that is used to connect to samba servers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look in `/var/lib/samba/usershares/`

If you want a graphical interface for samba shares, with a few more options, try `system-config-samba`

```
sudo apt-get install system-config-samba
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `/var/lib/samba/usershares/` was it! I wanted to add file creation masks (so written files don't end up being owned by `nobody` or another user) but that doesn't look possible under this configuration format. Might just be easier to hook the share out and stick it in the main samba config.

Comment: Try adding `force user = your_user_name` to the global section I found that advice on the mint forums http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=23143